# 401 Error after successfully obtaining access token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, slim

I have a problem with the authorization process in my app. I am able to obtain the access token, but only when I paste the url in my browser. It successfully spits out the token. But when I try to make a request from code to this specific url it says that I'm unauthorized. It's my first time trying oauth 2 and I've been sitting on this for about 2 days and can't solve the problem.

Edit

Request:

```
$params = array(
    'client_id'     => $this->clientID,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope'         => $this->scope,
    'state'         => 1,
);

$curl_response = RestClient::get( $this->url.'authorize?'.http_build_query($params) );
```

and the RestClient::get method:

```
public static function get( $url, array $curlopt = [] ){
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    if ( !empty( $curlopt ) ){
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $curlopt);
    }
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $curl_response;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like the part of code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: added @Nima hope it makes it more clear

Comment: First: missing the return url, second you cannot execute the get to the url, instead you must open a new tab with the builded url, when the user login it return to the reply url.